# Getting an error: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader, multiple-resultsets

I have 2 select statements in a stored procedure and getting result set in a data reader.
My objective is to merge the data from 2 selects into a single JSON string.

I am using nested do while and at the end of the while, I am getting an error

`Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.`

Below is the code:

```
try
        {
            
                con.Open();
            
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SPWorkMetaData";
            
            
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            
            List<Dictionary<String, Object>> tableRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            List<Dictionary<String, Object>> tableRow1 = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<String, Object> rows;
            
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                do 
                {
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(rd);

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        rows = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        int i = 1;
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            rows.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col].ToString());
                            i = i + 1;
                        }
                        tableRow.Add(rows);
                        status = "true";
                    }

                    retvalue = serializer.Serialize(tableRow).ToString();
                    //response = "{\"status\":\"" + status + "\",\"data\":" + retvalue + "}";
                    do
                    {
                        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                        dt1.Load(rd);
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
                        {
                            Dictionary<String, Object> rows1 = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
                            int i = 1;
                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
                            {
                                rows1.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col].ToString());
                                i = i + 1;
                            }
                            tableRow1.Add(rows1);
                            status = "true";
                        }
                        retvalue = serializer.Serialize(tableRow).ToString() + serializer.Serialize(tableRow1).ToString();
                        response = "{\"status\":\"" + status + "\",\"data\":" + retvalue + "}";
                    }
                    while (rd.Read());
                }
                while (rd.NextResult()) ;
               
                
            }

        }
```

Does the error means to convey that SQL connection is closed, if so, then it is mentioned that I am closing connection only in the finally block.

Need to understand this, kindly provide some guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: I think dt.Load(rd); closes your Reader

Comment: @Viliam Can you suggest its alternative ?

Comment: Load( should call NextResult internally. After calling it, isn't the result of the entire multiple select from your procedure in the DataTable? Then you would just work with the DataTable and create your json. Another, more laborious solution is not to use DataTable and load individual columns into your objects, then nested loops will work

Comment: The use of a dataset will get/return both tables from the SP, and then it is a simple matter to foreach rows on the 2 tables. See my posted code and proof of concept below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't note if the two tables returned are the same data structure?

and that then begs the question why a union query is not being used?

Also I don't think (doubt) you want to serialized a data row, since a data row has "extra" things like is the row dirty (been changed) and quite a few more "extra" attributes that I doubt you want to become part of the json result for the client.

So, lets pull the two tables (and ignore WHY a union query is not being used here!!!).

But, say I have two tables. tblHotels, and People - both of them have FirstName, lastname columns.

So, in theory, we need a clean data structure if we going to get a "reasonable" json string.

So, I would suggest this code:

```
    class PersonName
    {
        public string FirstName = "";
        public string LastName = "";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("Test2", conn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                conn.Open();
                DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
                da.Fill(ds);

                List<PersonName> MyNames = new List<PersonName>();

                // merge records form both tables (FirstName, LastName) into list
                foreach (DataRow OneRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    PersonName OneName = new PersonName();
                    OneName.FirstName = OneRow["FirstName"].ToString();
                    OneName.LastName = OneRow["LastName"].ToString();
                    MyNames.Add(OneName);
                }

                // now merge 2nd table
                foreach (DataRow OneRow in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
                {
                    PersonName OneName = new PersonName();
                    OneName.FirstName = OneRow["FirstName"].ToString();
                    OneName.LastName = OneRow["LastName"].ToString();
                    MyNames.Add(OneName);
                }

                // at this point, we now have a merge of both tables
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                string MyJSON = js.Serialize(MyNames);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. DataSet worked for me. Also I am not using model in my project as mentioned in your example code: `PersonName` and I am using List and Dictionary to write the result sets from database. Thanks for the idea of Union Query